# PHP MIN to exclude 0 value

Tags: php, variables, min, zero

I have 3 numeric values that I want to find the the lowest value. So I use `min()`, like this:

```
$last_activity = min($last_article, $last_comment, $last_video);
```

Is it possible to make `min()` exclude a variable if its value is 0? Note that the three variables are simple strings with a number like `10`, not arrays...

Comment: there is an example function of this on the [Manual page for min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) page in the comments

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, `min` has no such option. But *you* have the option to *filter* any `0` values first:

```
min(array_filter([$last_article, $last_comment, $last_video]))
```

Comment: Note that the three variables are simple strings with a number like 10, not arrays... will this still work?

Comment: Note that I'm creating an array `[..]` of the three values... Yes, it'll work.